# Return promise from graphql-request

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql

I'm using `graphql-request` to request the data

```
 return request('/graphql', flightDetailsQuery, variables).then(res => res);
```

This returns the as `__proto__: Object` but I need the `__proto__: Promise`. Can I specify it in request?

Comment: return request('/graphql', flightDetailsQuery, variables) will retrun promise